# $_POST Array issue PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, post

First of all, I am a newbie when it comes to coding, so please be kind and patient :)

What I am trying to do is to select two rows ('ID', 'name') from a MySQL table (categories), populate a drop down list with one row ('name'), and on submission of a form, pass the other ('ID') to another table.

Now, I can populate the drop down list, no problem. I have populated this with both 'ID' and 'name' to test that both of the variables I am using to hold this information, contain the correct data. But I cannot seem to $_POST the information.

I guess I am either looking at the wrong part of the array, or I am simply using the wrong code.

This is the code to create a new product, under a category from the database.

```
<?php

include 'db_config.php';

?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insert.php" method="post">
<h3>Add New Product</h3>
Category:

<!-- START OF categories (table) names (row) SQL QUERY -->

<? $sql = "SELECT ID, name FROM categories";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

echo "<select name='category_name'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $cat_ID=$row['ID'];
    $cat_name=$row['name'];
    extract($row);
    echo "<option value='" . $cat_ID . $cat_name . "'>" . $cat_ID . " " . $cat_name ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>

<!--END OF SQL QUERY -->

<br>
Code: <input type="text" name="code"><br>
Name: <input type="text" name="prod_name"><br>
Description: <input type="textarea" name="description"><br>
Image: <input type="file" name="image"><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

For now, I am just echoing this out in the insert.php script, to test the code above. This is a snippet of the insert.php script.

```
echo "ID: " .  $_POST['$row["ID"]'] . "<br>";
echo "Category: " .  $_POST['$row["name"]'] . "<br>";
echo "Code: ". $_POST['code'] . "<br>";
echo "Name: " . $_POST['prod_name'] . "<br>";
echo "Description: ". $_POST['description'] . "<br>";
echo "Image: " . $_POST['image'] . "<br>";
```

Don't worry about the last line above. I know this needs to be $_FILES, and I have all this covered. I have stopped writing the data to the table until I get my issue fixed. In the full script, image are being upload to "/images" and the location stored in the table. This all works fine.

The problem is with the first two lines, as they are blank when returned. I thought I was storing the information correctly, as I am calling the same variables to populate the drop down list, but I cannot seem to $_POST it.

Does that makes sense?

Thanks to all who help me. Once day I will be as good as you....I hope.

TIA

Smurf.

Comment: `$_POST['$row["ID"]']` is not a valid variable. Only stuff inside the `<form>` tags gets sent via post, you need to either echo the other variables into a hidden field inside the post, or store them as a session variable

Comment: print_r() is a very good function that lets you know whats coming from your form. Try using print_r($_POST) and you will notice whats the problem here.

Comment: I did wonder if this was the problem. So if I have a PHP statement within a form, it will not get passed? SOrt of makes sense that.

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST` variable you want,  is inside `category_name`

Cuz your select is...

```
<select name='category_name'>
```

So you need to get it by...

```
$_POST['category_name'];
```

Which will return whatever you've assigned to the select options...ie

```
2  Name
```

2 being the `ID`, and Name being the `name`

But if you then want to use that ID to retrieve from DB or anything, you're gonna have to explode that apart...like so....to get each piece.

```
$array = explode(" ", $_POST['category_name']);
```

That will leave you with...

```
  $array[0] = ID
  $array[1] = Name
```

But I would avoid all that part, by just assigning the ID to the value only...like so..

```
echo "<option value = '".$cat_ID."'> ".$cat_name." </option>";
```

That way you just pass the ID and have access to it on the other side.

Comment: <Slaps head> Yes of course. I have gone round in circles but started there. Okay, so how do I get the individual pieces of date out?

Comment: I dunno...I dont see any 'date' code above, so I cant answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I have just seen all of your reply. I am sure that is the answer.

Comment: Yeah typos....don't ya love 'em!!! I haven't even started with dates yet...anyway, thanks KyleK, I wasn't thinking properly and getting all confused with some basic HTML functions. All sorted now, and I am getting the ID back. 6 hours on this would you believe!!!

Answer (score 0):

this bellow:

```
echo "ID: " .  $_POST['$row["ID"]'] . "<br>";
echo "Category: " .  $_POST['$row["name"]'] . "<br>";
```

is wrong, select element has its name `category_name`, so, instead of this, you should 
do:

```
echo "Category: " .  $_POST['category_name'] . "<br>";
```

Comment: I suggest you to put only ID for value under category select element, and then update other table only with ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "ID: " .  $_POST['$row["ID"]'] . "<br>";
echo "Category: " .  $_POST['$row["name"]'] . "<br>";
```

There aren't any form elements with those names in your form (`$row["ID"]` and `$row["name"]`).  Those would be *really* strange names for a form element anyway.  The form element you're creating is:

```
<select name='category_name'>
```

So the selected value would be posted as:

```
$_POST['category_name']
```

The `option` elements for that `select` appear to have values which are a combination of ID and Name:

```
"<option value='" . $cat_ID . $cat_name . "'>"
```

Thus, if the user selects an option with a value of `1SomeName` then `$_POST['category_name']` will evaluate to `'1SomeName'`.

It's certainly unconventional to use the combination of ID *and* Name for the option values, but it should work.  The problem is presents is that you now have a composite string which needs to be parsed in order to be useful.  Generally what one would do is just use the ID as the value and the Name as the display.  All you *should* need to use it throughout the code is the ID.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying. I don't really need the ID to be in the drop down list, it was there to ensure I was getting the data. What I want is just the category 'name', but, I want to store the 'ID' of the select category in another table.